# Long runtime/crash when using int[] as key in hashmap

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am following this lesson on dynamic programming: https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk?t=2330
I found that for some reason if I use a HashMap key with int[], using a large m and n value will take a very long time or crash. If I use a key that is a String instead, it works as expected.

**Working Code**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(gridTraveler(18, 18, map));
    }

    /**
     * Grid Traveler problem
     * */
    public static Long gridTraveler(int m, int n, HashMap<String, Long> memo){
        String key = m + "," + n;
        if(memo.containsKey(key)){
            return memo.get(key);
        }
        if(m == 1 && n == 1) {
            return 1L;
        }
        if(m == 0 || n == 0){
            return 0L;
        }
        memo.put(key, gridTraveler(m - 1, n, memo) + gridTraveler(m, n - 1, memo));
        return memo.get(key);
    }
```

**Broken Code**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<int[], Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(gridTraveler(18, 18, map));
    }

    /**
     * Grid Traveler problem
     * */
    public static Long gridTraveler(int m, int n, HashMap<int[], Long> memo){
        int[] key = new int[]{m,n};
        if(memo.containsKey(key)){
            return memo.get(key);
        }
        if(m == 1 && n == 1) {
            return 1L;
        }
        if(m == 0 || n == 0){
            return 0L;
        }
        memo.put(key, gridTraveler(m - 1, n, memo) + gridTraveler(m, n - 1, memo));
        return memo.get(key);
    }
```

**Question:** Why does an int[] key cause my code to crash compared to just using a String as a key?

Comment: I see this question has been down voted. Can anyone explain what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays do not override the `equals()` or `hashCode()` method from `java.lang.Object`, but the `java.lang.String` class does. So, your `Map` will grow with new objects all the time until it crashes due to memory limits, even though there are already "equal" arrays as keys in the `Map`. But from the point of view of java, they are not "equal".

Comment: Does that mean it's bad practice to use an array as a key for maps or should be avoided?

Comment: No, it might be fine to use objects as keys, which don't override the `equals()`/`hashCode()` methods, as long as you don't expect that they are "same" to each other. But if you *do* and have multiple instances of the "same value", then you can't use these objects as keys.

Answer (score 0):

What's more, you could use List as the key of Map, then different List objects with same elements are considered equal.

Declare the map with `HashMap<List<Integer>, Long>`. Call `Arrays.stream(new int[]{1, 2, 3}).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` to convert an int array to a List.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, which would make particularly good sense for larger arrays that take time to copy, would be to wrap each array in an object that properly implements `equals` and `hashCode`.  You could use `java.util.Arrays.equals` and `java.util.Arrays.hashCode` as the guts of the two methods.

Similarly, you could just call `java.util.Arrays.hashCode` to convert each of your arrays to a key that will properly "equal" another key when the two original arrays contained the same values.